# Filter pandas DataFrame based on last_valid_index value

Tags: python, pandas

is there any proper way of filtering pandas DataFrame based on `last_valid_index` of the column?

For example, I want to have all rows where last valid index value has the format of `(\d{13})`.

Input:

```
      0  ...    15             16             17   18
24  10.0 ...  1107  8712566328208            NaN  NaN
25   6.0 ...  363K           1243  8712100849084  NaN
26  10.0 ...   758  3251510550005            NaN  NaN
27   8.0 ...  245K            780  3560070774425  NaN
29   6.0 ...  1485  7613034528971            NaN  NaN
29   6.0 ...  1485          test1            NaN  NaN
29   6.0 ...  1485            280           test  NaN
```

Output:

```
      0  ...    15             16             17   18
24  10.0 ...  1107  8712566328208            NaN  NaN
25   6.0 ...  363K           1243  8712100849084  NaN
26  10.0 ...   758  3251510550005            NaN  NaN
27   8.0 ...  245K            780  3560070774425  NaN
29   6.0 ...  1485  7613034528971            NaN  NaN
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `.apply` with `axis=1` to get the `last_valid_index` per row, then use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to get the actual values, and [`.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to compare them to the regex.

try this:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

import re

s = """
      0      15             16             17   18
24  10.0   1107  8712566328208            NaN  NaN
25   6.0   363K           1243  8712100849084  NaN
26  10.0    758  3251510550005            NaN  NaN
27   8.0   245K            780  3560070774425  NaN
29   6.0   1485  7613034528971            NaN  NaN
30   6.0   1485          test1            NaN  NaN
31   6.0   1485            280           test  NaN"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s+")

last_valid_indices = df.apply(lambda row: row.last_valid_index(), axis=1)
last_valid_vals = pd.Series(df.lookup(last_valid_indices.index, last_valid_indices.values), index=last_valid_indices.index)
print(df[last_valid_vals.str.match("\d{13}")])
```

Output:

```
       0    15             16             17  18
24  10.0  1107  8712566328208            NaN NaN
25   6.0  363K           1243  8712100849084 NaN
26  10.0   758  3251510550005            NaN NaN
27   8.0  245K            780  3560070774425 NaN
29   6.0  1485  7613034528971            NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `ffill`

```
df[(pd.to_numeric(df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1],errors='coerce')//1e12).between(1,9)]
       0  ...    15             16             17  18
24  10.0  ...  1107  8712566328208            NaN NaN
25   6.0  ...  363K           1243  8712100849084 NaN
26  10.0  ...   758  3251510550005            NaN NaN
27   8.0  ...  245K            780  3560070774425 NaN
29   6.0  ...  1485  7613034528971            NaN NaN
```